# Java Scanner Get Next Delimiter

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to capture commands where '\' can be used to extend commands onto multiple lines. Thus, a possible delimiter can be:

```
Pattern assignment = Pattern.compile("[^\\\\]\\n");
```

Of course, this has the problem of chopping off the last non '\' character before '\n'. I was attempting to recover that character by attempting the following:

Since to a Scanner its input is in the form of: T1 D1 T2 D2 T3 D3.... where T# and D# correspond to token and delimiter number '#' respectively, I thought this would work:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\?\\s+");

String residue = file.findInLine(assignment);
String curToken = file.next().trim();

if(residue == null)
   residue = "";
else
   residue = residue.trim();

Scanner tokens = new Scanner(curToken + residue).useDelimiter(p);
```

Instead of getting the concatenation of T1 and D1, findInLine, which is supposed to ignore the scanner's delimiter, returns null when the pattern is the same as the delimiter! Can anyone explain this odd behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out how to get the behavior I wanted, but I still don't understand why what I was attempting did not work.

The solution is to use negative look-behind which does not consume the non-'\':

```
Pattern assignment = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\\\)\\n");
```